# Pentaho DI Server Unable to Read Repository

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am unable to read the repository when opening the spoon tool.. (Data Integration tool)

Unable to read repository with id [PentahoEnterpriseRepositor]. RepositoryMeta is not available.

2015/11/02 13:04:26 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: /root/.kettle/repositories.xml

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: spoon/DI server version?

Comment: Is this community edition or enterprise edition?

Comment: It is Community Edition. Spoon / DI version : 6.0.0.0

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing the repositories.xml. but i m stuck in one issue now. I am not able to connect to DI repository (connecting spoon and DI server) is an issue now.

Comment: I have put it as seperate thread question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474797/not-able-to-connect-to-di-repository-server-from-spoon

Comment: ok I will have a look on that. Post the solution as an answer so somebody will be benefited from it

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the repositories.xml., and the next time when i opened spoon, i didnt get the error.

Now I get a different problem,.when connecting spoon with di server. earlier i was able to connect. now there is a problem when accessing.

posted as a seperate question : stackoverflow.com/questions/33474797/