# Not able to Connect to DI repository server from Spoon

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, spoon, pentaho-ctools

I am trying to connect to DI server from Spoon..(Spoon with DI server) - DI server is running fine. 
Few days back when I tried it was working fine. suddenly I dont know where does the issue come from.

[image: I dont find DI repository in the list to connect]

I followed the steps from the documentation : http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftask_pdi_usr_connecting_2_repo.html

How do I add DI repository to this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like Spoon you are using does not contain the plugin for working with EE repository. The plugin should exist in `plugins/repositories/pur-repository-plugin`. If there are some files there, then Spoon likely failed to load it and logs are needed to investigate the case further

Comment: is it anything to do with repositories.xml file?

Comment: `~/.kettle/repositories.xml` contains information about repositories you have already connected. Have you ever established a connection with DI repo? If so, it should have stored in the file. However, the absence of the file (or whatever else related to it) cannot be the reason of inability to establish a brand new connection.

Comment: okay. I removed the file since I was getting an issue when starting the Pentaho Spoon. 
Earlier, I setup Pentaho Spoon with DI using the below link http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftask_pdi_usr_connecting_2_repo.html

but now, I am not able to find the DI repository in the list of repository type....

Comment: I am still not able to figure out where the issue is .. is there any way to bring up the DI Repository in that ?

Comment: Does `{SPOON_INSTALLATION_PATH}/plugins/repositories/pur-repository-plugin` folder exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93978/discussion-between-andrey-khayrutdinov-and-soundarya-thiagarajan).

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 types of DI repository for Spoon:

- file-based repository (free)
- db-based repository (free)
- jackrabbit (JCR) based repository also known as EE repository (only
  for EE)

Typically when you download Spoon or how do they call it now 'Pentaho Data Integration' you download it in form of zip with CE version of Spoon or some kind of 'installer' bundle for EE. For ubuntu that should be binary installer.
Installer contains CE Spoon version inside packaged with EE plugins, EE DI server and some other functionalities.

When you install Spoon using EE installer it is install all EE infrastructure as far as *temporary EE licenses*.

So since temporary license will expire - EE functionality as far as EE plugins just stops to work (for some cases stop to start).

Usually a warning should be shown when attempt to connect to EE repository. Or if no warning - will be just exception stack-trace. Of if no stacktrace - some menu items will just silently disappears. To draw dialog box 'select repository' Spoon inspects it's run-time for available repository providers and list them accordingly.

As mentioned above to be able to connect to EE DI repostiory required to have:

1. Spoon installed and able to launch
2. pur-repository-plugin installed
3. DI server up and running (on separate tomcat instance)
4. EE license still active to have 'pur-repository-plugin' able to
   connect to EE repository and 'DI server' able to start

If you have any stack-traces - that would be extremely helpful to determine what is really going wrong.

Hope it will help.